# adding a script tag dynamically with document.write

Tags: javascript, html

I dont know if this is a good idea but I am trying to add a script using document.write in my HTML document that would add a script only if the browser is online.

```
<script>
var online = navigator.onLine;
if(online){
  document.write("<script src='./api.js'></script>");
}
</script>
```

the thing is the browser is stoping at the first closing `</script>` tag that is inside the document.write function, causing everything else to be interpreted as HTML ( `");` appears renedered in the html) , I know that I am doing something wrong but would like to know what

Comment: Note: [Why split the <script> tag when writing it with document.write()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write)

Comment: Note the return value of `navigator.onLine` wither true or false will not definitively let you know wither the user has an active internet connection or not.

Comment: this is not an app for the general public , it's an isolated app that i will be showcasing on a screen using chrome at a gallery and therefore external users and browser fallbacks have been disregarded

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
document.write("<script src='./api'></"+"script>");
```

You're right. Browsers read all `<script> ... </script>` block and pass them to JS engine. So, if you want to write `</script>` you should break it.

**Note** Using document.write to add JavaScript to document is not a good idea.

Comment: It works. Thanks. It may not be a good idea, but for quick fix for footer page includes, worked great.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** please see this thread and answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8024286/2192152

Here is a code I used for a personal website:

```
/* *************************************************************
 *  Loading any js file.
 ************************************************************** */
staticPath ='./js/';
vendorPath='./js/vendor/';

src = [
    {f:'jquery-1.8.3.min.js', n:1},
    {f:'jquery-ui-1.9.2.js', n:1},
    {f:'lib.js', n:0},        
];


for (var i in src)
{
    if (src[i].n === 0) document.write('<' + 'script type="text/javascript" src="' + staticPath + src[i].f + '"></sc' + 'ript>');
    else  document.write('<' + 'script type="text/javascript" src="' + vendorPath + src[i].f + '"></sc' + 'ript>');
}
```

As you can see you should split the string containing you script call. I unfortunately don't know much more of why this is needed.

Note: I tried many setting and the one I provide you here is the fastest one in terms of load time (using chrome)

Comment: also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "./api.js";
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

also are you missing extension on api? should it be api.js?

Comment: it somehow works without the extension as a js file but adding it would be more intuitive, i will edit my question for the sake of better understanding

Comment: just change `api` in the line `script.src = "./api";` to correct filename after you change it